# IIS : Idle Time out settings in application pools

Tags: iis, time, timeout

I have hosted my application on IIS 6.0 and changed the idle time-out value and cookie state time-out values to 40mins.
But my application logs out after 30mins.

Why is this happening? Is there any upper limit to this?
Also, I cannot give 0(infinite) time out.

Comment: You may also need to set the value of PeriodicRestartTime. If the value of IdleTimeout is less than the value of PeriodicRestartTime, IIS sets both properties to their default values.

Comment: Do you mean, i have update Recycling value also to 40mins?

Comment: Yes. You can try it.